# Rename (append) word file based on a bookmark using Word VBA Macros

Tags: vba, ms-word

Using Word VBA Macros, can I rename (append) a .doc file with value contained in a bookmark.

for eg, I have a bookmark "name" present in thousands of documents in a folder 'source'.  Each file has a different value in the bookmark, eg, Richard, Alex, William, etc.

If my file is, say, "123.doc", containing bookmark "name" with value "Richard"
then I want the word file to be renamed "123Richard.doc"

and if 456.doc, again containing same bookmark "name" with value "Alex",
then I want the word fiile to be renamed "456Alex.doc"

I want to use only word VBA Macros.

Thank you.

Comment: any suggestions please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To rename the single doc you can use this:

```
Public Sub updateName()
    Dim name As String

    If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("BookMarkName") Then
        'extract the name from the bookmark
        name = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("BookmarkName").Range.Text

        'Save the doc with the new name
        ActiveDocument.SaveAs _
               Left(ActiveDocument.FullName, Len(ActiveDocument.FullName) - 4) & _
               name & Right(ActiveDocument.FullName, 4)

    End If

End Sub
```

To do this in all docs in a specific subfolder you can use a traversal macro, check out this code from VBA express: http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=76

It will open alle files in a specific folder and all its subfolder. Just add a call to updateName inside the loop:

```
If Right(strName, 4) = ".doc" Or Right(strName, 4) = ".dot" Then 
            Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=strPath & "\" & strName, _ 
            ReadOnly:=False, Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto) 

            'Call the macro that performs work on the file pasing a reference to it

            'change the name of the open document
            changeDoc 

             'we close saving changes
            wdDoc.Close wdSaveChanges 
End If
```

**UPDATE**:

Rename the document based on the values in two bookmarks:

```
Public Sub updateName2()
    Dim firstName, lastName As String

    'make sure the bookmarks exist
    If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("FNAME") And _
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("LNAME") Then

        'extract the names
        firstName = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("FNAME").Range.Text
        lastName = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("LNAME").Range.Text

        'save the document with the new name
         ActiveDocument.SaveAs _
             ActiveDocument.path & "\" & firstName & _
             " " & lastName & ActiveDocument.name
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Glad to hear! Could you please mark the question as resolved?

Comment: @boogiehound You might want to comment again and "flag" vicki (put an ampersand in front of the name) to make sure she receives a notification in her inbox.

Comment: @vicki Could you please mark the question as resolved?

Comment: @Cindy  Thanks for the info!

Comment: Dim name As String
Dim path As String
         'extract the name from the bookmark
        name = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("FNAME").Range.Text
        name2 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("LNAME").Range.Text
        'Save the doc with the new name

        ActiveDocument.SaveAs _
               Left(ActiveDocument.FullName, Len(ActiveDocument.FullName) - 4) & _
               name2 & "_" & name & Right(ActiveDocument.FullName, 4)

Comment: This changes 123.doc to 123 Obama _ Barack.doc   ----How do I change to Obama_Barack123.doc         --- that is, how to remove spaces between and place the name first before the file name ?

Comment: ok, i found the 'space' problem (because of spaces in form field); but how do i place this as a prefix, rather than a suffix.